# Extracting certain pattern from log

Tags: perl, unix, sed, awk, grep

I need to extract requests from a log file that look like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<vehicleRegistration>
.... XML in between ....
.... XML in between ....
.... XML in between ....
.... XML in between ....
... at nth line there is line like this <vehicle id="2312313"></vehicle>
.... XML in between ....
.... XML in between ....
</vehicleRegistration>
```

The important issue is that vehicleRegistration can be 5 lines and sometimes 17, its changeable. It is where my current grep has failed, I used :

```
grep -A 13 "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>" vehicle.log
```

Also another issue is that, sometimes a request can be sent 2 or more times because the service might be unavailable for some reason, so there might be same multiple requests in the file.

I should also rule out duplicate requests, the way to know that the request is duplicate by comparing nth line(not the last line) `<vehicle id="2312313"></vehicle>`, if vehicle id repeated than its a duplicate.

What is the way you would solve this? Suggestions, code, pseudo-code, anything is welcome.

**EDIT :**

Log file is not an xml file, its just a file containing some small percentage of xml requests and I can't parse it as XML

**EDIT II :**

I extracted only the vehicle registration part, using @eugene y one line command `perl -nle 'm{<vehicleRegistration>} .. m{</vehicleRegistration>} and print' logfile` , how can I get rid of duplicates, those nodes that have same vehicle id, I want to keep only one copy of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [XPath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_intro.asp) to recover XML element nodes. There are lots of frameworks for various modern scripting languages.

With Perl, you might do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::XPath;

my $file = 'vehicleRegistration.xml';
my $xp = XML::XPath->new(filename => $file);

print "Vehicle id: ".$xp->find('//vehicle/@id')."\n";
```

If you need to, parse your log file to extract the XML document portion, and then run the XPath expression on it to recover the element and data you want.

Comment: thank you for your response, what does this do above? prints vehicle id? I need to use this vehicle id to get rid of the whole  <vehicleRegistration>anything between</vehicleRegistration>

Comment: Yes, this takes the chunk of XML you've excised and prints out the vehicle id.

Comment: I'd like to delete vehicleRegistration nodes,  that contain same vehicle id as any other vehicleRegistration nodes, how about would I go doing that? pseudo-code or code would be great, or tutorial or anything that might help me get this done. tnx

Comment: Keep a hash table (`%registrations`) that uses the vehicle id as the key. If there isn't a value associated with the vehicle id key, add the vehicleRegistration node as the value (`if (! defined $registrations{$vehicleId}) { $registrations{$vehicleId} = $regXmlValue; }`). If there is a value for the vehicle id key, just keep going. At the end, read out the hash table for a list of vehicleRegistration nodes that are associated with unique vehicle ids (`foreach $id (sort keys %registrations) { print $registrations{$id}; } `). HTH.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML%3a%3aSimple) (or other XML parser) to extract the data. `Data::Dumper` can be used to inspect data structures.

Update: you can extract the `vehicleRegistration` elements like this:

```
open my $fh, '<', 'logfile' or die $!;     
my $xml = ""; 

while (<$fh>) {
    if ( m{<vehicleRegistration>} .. m{</vehicleRegistration>}) {
        $xml .= $_; 
    }   
}
```

Or with a perl one-liner:

```
perl -nle 'm{<vehicleRegistration>} .. m{</vehicleRegistration>} and print' logfile
```

Comment: I just edited my question, the log file is not xml file it just contains some requests so I can't parse it as xml

Comment: @c0mrade - How are these XML snippets separated? Can you extract these XML blocks and parse them as eugene suggests?

Comment: @eumiro @eugene y  Yes I've seperated XML part, how can I get rid of the duplicates?

Comment: @c0mrade - pipe the result to sort and uniq, i. e. `sort | uniq -d`

Comment: @Luca Martini when vehicle id is duplicate I want to get rid of the whole <vehicleRegistration>anything between</vehicleRegistration>

Answer (score 1):

use the awk or gawk command in unix to extract the registration...

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f 

/^<vehicleRegistration>/ { printit="true" } # set the print flag on
printit ~ "true" { print }                  # if printflag set print
/^</vehicleRegistration>{ printit="false" } # turn print flag off
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) (and depending on what you want to do with the result, possibly [Xslt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xslt))

There are command line utilities for this, [here, for example](http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/commandline.html)

Comment: Sorry I just edited my question, the log file is not xml file it just contains some requests so I can't parse it as xml

Comment: Sure you can :) extract the text between <vehicleRegistration> and </vehicleRegistration> and pass that to an XML parser...